# swift: How to use protocols in place of abstract class?

Tags: java, swift, protocols, abstract-class

I wanted to know how can i use protocols in the place of abstract class.Given below is the scenario written with abstract class that i want to implement using protocols in swift:

```
public abstract class ModelA
{
  protected int productQuantity;
  protected String productUrl;
}

class ModelB extends ModelA
{
  // I want to access ModelA members here
}
```

I want to implement the above functionality using protocols in swift.
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: `protocol ModelA {
    var productQuantity :Int{get set}
    var productUrl:String {get set}
}

class ModelB:ModelA{
    
    var productQuantity :Int = 10
    var productUrl:String  = "Some URl"
    
}`

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple example and also for more details you can look at [Apple Docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Protocols.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH25-ID267)

```
protocol Shape {
    var width: Double { get set}
    var height: Double { get set}
    func area() -> Double
    func perimeter() -> Double
}

class Rectangle:Shape
{
    var width: Double
    var height: Double

    init()
    {
        width = 0.0
        height = 0.0
    }
    convenience init(width:Double, height:Double)
    {
        self.init()
        self.width = width
        self.height = height
    }
    func area() -> Double {
        return width * height
    }

    func perimeter() -> Double {
        return 2 * (width + height)
    }
}
```

|

```
    var rect = Rectangle(width: 5.0, height: 5.0)
    print(rect.area())
    print(rect.perimeter())

    rect = Rectangle()
    print(rect.area())
    print(rect.perimeter())

    rect.width = 10
    rect.height = 10
    print(rect.area())
    print(rect.perimeter())
```

Comment: From what i have read protocol work as an interface in swift.But that forces me to implement all the properties or function in the derived class.What if i want some of the properties in one derived class and some properties in another derived class?which i can achieve using abstract class.

Comment: In Swift, you can't have optional property or method in protocol however you can declare by making it objc compliance with @objc(For more info visit - https://devforums.apple.com/message/994834#994834). If you want to use some of the properties in class 1 and some in class 2 that simply means either those properties should not be declared in protocol or just assign some default value and don't use them.

Comment: Taking your example for instance, if i have another variable called radius in Shape protocol and a class Circle that implements shape to calculate area and perimeter and Circle class requires only radius neither width nor height.How should i implement that? since using optional property is not recommended so i cannot use that.

Comment: You can use Computed Properties(https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Properties.html) for the same. In case of circle your radius=width=height where radius is computed property so you need not to declare another property instead you can have stored property as radius.

Answer (score 1):

The Implementation of the protocol should be:

```
protocol ModelA {
    // props
    var productQuantity: Int { get set }
    var productUrl:String { get set }
}
```

*"I want to access ModelA members here"*, actually you HAVE TO implement `ModelA` properties in `ModelB`. Otherwise, you will get a compile error saying:

[image]

ModelB:

```
class ModelB: ModelA {
    // default values
    var productQuantity: Int = 0
    var productUrl: String = ""

    // you can remove the default values after implementing 'init':
    init(productQuantity: Int, productUrl: String) {
        self.productQuantity = productQuantity
        self.productUrl = productUrl
    }
}
```

For more information about protocol, check [Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Protocols.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH25-ID267).

Answer (score 1):

you can write this:

```
@objc protocol modelA
{
  @objc optional productQuantity:Int { get set }
  @objc optional productUrl:String { get set }
}
```

And then use it in a class

```
class ModelB: ModelA {
  // you can implement OR NOT the attributes here
}
```

from apple doc:

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Protocols.html

> You can define optional requirements for protocols, These requirements
>   do not have to be implemented by types that conform to the protocol.
>   Optional requirements are prefixed by the optional modifier as part of
>   the protocol’s definition. Optional requirements are available so that
>   you can write code that interoperates with Objective-C. Both the
>   protocol and the optional requirement must be marked with the @objc
>   attribute. Note that @objc protocols can be adopted only by classes
>   that inherit from Objective-C classes or other @objc classes. They
>   can’t be adopted by structures or enumerations.

But honestly, It's not really the best approach if you want to really keep your code clear. Abstract classes don't define clearly who will implement functions or not. I don't know what you are trying to achieve in the end but maybe extensions could help you add functions to some classes without having to define them in a protocol before hands.